# Cannot set the default value of a dropdown in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hook-form

I have tried to set the default value in a dropdown. What is happening here is `applicant.state_of_organization` is coming from a redux state and when the `Controller` renders, the redux state is not available at that time. What to do in this case.

```
<Controller
    name="state_of_organization"
    as={Select}
    styles={dropDownstyle}
    options={States}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={States.filter(option => option.label === applicant.state_of_organization)}
/>
```

How can I assign the default value in this case ?

Comment: Add a check `States&&States.length>0?(filter):''` .

Comment: what's that select? is that react-select.

Comment: Try this
    `let defaultValue={}
    If(applicant.state_of_organization){ defaultValue= States.filter(option => option.label === applicant.state_of_organization)}` and in your controller use defaultValue variable

Comment: can you use useEffect with setValue or reset?